# Ember: Iterating through childViews

Tags: coffeescript, ember.js

I need to iterate through a collection of child views (Which are UI Widgets) and tell them to remove themselves from the app. I have ensured that all the childViews are present in the collection, however this code will only call removeIfSelected() on a few of the childViews/widgets at a time:

```
 widgets = container.get('childViews')
 widget.removeIfSelected() for widget in widgets
```

For example, if there are 3 widgets, the first time this is run (via delete button) 2 widgets are removed. I have to click the button again to remove the last widget.

If there are 2 it will remove one widget. If there are 4 or more, all but 2 widgets are removed, and I have to click delete 2 more times to remove the last two.

My initial solution was to run the loop 3 times which guarantees all widgets are removed, however this did not pass code review and I have to find a real solution. I am not sure if this is a coffeescript problem or an Ember.js problem. How can I ensure that the loop executes completely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like `widget.removeIfSelected()` is altering the `widgets` array behind your back so as soon as remove something, the lengths and indexes in your `for` loop get all screwed up. Consider this loop:

```
a = [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]
for e, i in a
    console.log(i) if(i % 2 == 0)
```

That will obviously produce `0, 2, 4` in the console. However, this:

```
a = [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]
for e, i in a
    a.splice(i, 1) if(i % 2 == 0)
console.log(a)
```

leaves you with `[1, 2, 4, 5]` in `a` because `a` is being modified while it is being looped over.

There are two common solutions to this:

1. Iterate backwards so that changes don't affect anything that's coming up, they only affect things that you've already been through.
2. Make a copy of what you're iterating over so that you're iterating over one thing and changing something else.

The first would look like this:

```
for i in [widgets.length - 1 .. 0] by -1
    widget.removeIfSelected()
```

The second would look like this:

```
widgets = clone(container.get('childViews'))
widget.removeIfSelected() for widget in widgets
```

Where `clone` is whatever you have available to make (shallow) copies of an array. If you have Underscore kicking around then you could use [`_.clone`](http://underscorejs.org/#clone):

```
widgets = _(container.get('childViews')).clone()
```

You could also do it by hand:

```
clone = (a) -> e for e in a
```

Comment: Can't believe I overlooked this. The cloning method worked perfectly. Thank you.

Comment: I think you can use the built-in ember.js function toArray(), `container.get('childViews').toArray()) as the clone method.